# Finding a locally bounded real-valued function on $(0,1)$ whose integral is not easily computed on $(0,1)$.

Tags: integration, limits, analysis

I need to find a locally bounded (continuous implies locally bounded) real valued function $f$ on $(0,1)$ such that the following conditions are met:

- for every small $\epsilon > 0$, f is bounded and integrable on $[\epsilon , 1 - \epsilon]$
- $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^{1 - \epsilon} f$ exists
- the upper and lower sum, with respect to any partition $P$ of $(0,1)$ is not defined.

I've thought about the problem but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. The function I initially considered was $sin(\frac{2\pi}{x})$ since it satisfies the first condition. With regard to the third condition, I can see that the sup of the first subinterval of any partition of $(0,1)$ would be $1$, and the inf would be $-1$. I'm not sure in what cases the upper and lower sums are undefined. I'm not sure how to check the second condition for this function.

For context, I have studied Darboux integration in a previous intro to analysis course, and I am currently studying the use of partitions of unity to define integration over arbitrary open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I believe the purpose of this exercise is to motivate the necessity of using partitions of unity to evaluate certain integrals.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt x} -\frac 1 {\sqrt {1-x}}$ is such a function. (I am sure you meant $\epsilon \to 0$ not  $\epsilon \to \infty$)

Comment: Thank you! I made the edit. I was able to check the conditions.